# How to pass multiple sql files in impala command line

Tags: hadoop, impala

I have multiple .sql files like (1.sql, 2.sql, 3.sql) and it contains the following queries.

1.sql:

```sql
show databases;
```

2.sql:

```sql
use default;
```

3.sql:

```sql
show tables;
```

4.sql:

```sql
select count(*) from employee limit 5;
```

I am trying to pass the files as mentioned below.

```
impala-shell -f 1.sql; 2.sql; 3.sql; 4.sql
```

In this case the command is executing only `1.sql` and exiting from the terminal stating that `2.sql .. command not found`.

I know I can put all the above queries in a single .sql file, but my question is how to pass multiple .sql files via command line.

Can someone suggest me how can I pass multiple .sql files to impala from command line?

Comment: seperating by semicolon wont work. can you put 1.sql; 2.sql; 3.sql; 4.sql in a list file and then call `impala-shell -f file.sql` using a for loop. Or you can insert all file contant in a final_file.iql and call it using `impala-shell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be quite simple if you have Impala version 2.3 or higher, because then you can [substitute query file for `stdin`](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_shell_options.html). So something like that should work:

```
$ cat 1.sql 2.sql 3.sql | impala-shell -i "impala-host:port" -f -
```

(mind the last dash `-`)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put 2 sql file in the same way but what it does is just read the file but not execute these 2 files inside impala shell and version currently I am using is 3.2

Comment: did you see any error? Can you copy the command here which you have used.